# Views to display different text than field

Tags: 7, views, uri

I have added a field in Article content type,

1. field_url : contains external URL

I made a view to display the items in table format, Now my problem is to display as small text as possible in table.

I want to display Yes or No for `field_url`. If somebody have filled the field while adding content then instead of displaying whole URL I want to display only **Yes** with a link, if the field was empty I want to display **No**.

Comment: *"currently I am using trimmed text of 1 to display the result"* - so you have already solved that, right? What are you asking, then?

Comment: Is that the right way to solve it? I was thinking some dynamic way of solving it

Comment: There are no really right and wrong solutions, only ones that meets your needs and ones that does not. If some of your needs are not met, add that to your question.

Comment: Ok, what about `field_url` how do I achieve it ? ---- I have already mentioned in question while asking, if there is any better way to solve it...

Comment: "Better" and "elegant" are weasel words, means different things to different people. And please ask one question at a time, *trimming* and *yes/no* are pretty much separate topics.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bala's answer is also working... After playing with views for few hours I found another way of implementing **Yes** or **No** in URL with link.

At first I installed [link module](https://drupal.org/project/link) and changed the `field_url` type from text to Link type.

In Views, I clicked on the URL field, went to **No Result Behaviour** tab and put the text **No** in *No Result Text*.

I opened the **Rewerite Results** tab, **checked** on the *Rewrite the Output of this field* and in the Text, I entered **Yes**

I also **check** on *Output this field as Link*. In the *Link Path* I used the Token `[field_url-url]`. This also gives my desired result of **Yes** with Link and **No** if empty.

Comment: Simplest method !!! :)

Comment: @Bala, thanks.... I was playing with [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) as you mentioned, but it is still in Dev release. I couldn't take risk of using module in dev for production, so, had to look for alternatives.

Comment: Suppose if you encounter a problem then search for other alternative, otherwise Dev release will no affect your website and also check the people using the module, Its really high

Comment: Thx - this gave me a pointer for how to have a 0 replaced with No and a 1 replaced with a Yes. so simple

Answer (score 3):

**"To display Yes or No for field_url"** - I done something similar to this but with Drupal 6 and [Views Custom Field](https://drupal.org/project/views_customfield).

So for Drupal 7, I think you need to use [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) and add Custom Field:PHP field in your view and make conditions.

```
<?php 

$static = $this->view->display_handler->get_handlers('field');

$x=$static['tid_1']->last_render;
$y=$static['tid_2']->last_render;

if($x !== null)
{
echo "<a href='#Your link'>"."Yes"."</a>";
}
else
{
echo "NO";
}

?>
```

note: tid_1, tid_2 are field tokens, instead change it with your fields token.

Comment: Thank you Bala for the input. Yes `Views PHP` is great way to include PHP logic inside views. I will explore more about it in Views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [display suit](https://drupal.org/project/DS) module and write some tpl file for your content type in a specific view mode you choose for your view and suggest it to drupal.
EDITED :
first create view mode,then render your view as a display suit with a view mode you created , and then in for example node--article--[your view_mode machine name].tpl.php write the condition you want based on a field data ! I don't know if I'm clear enough,but do a little research then you understand how it is related

Comment: if you have any more questions about how to work with ds module, feel free to ask ! ;)

Comment: How it relate to this question

Comment: I've updated my answer